# Remove all but one duplicate from array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[
  { :color => 'red', :animal => 'dog' },
  { :color => 'blue', :animal => 'cat' },
  { :color => 'yellow', :animal => 'frog' },
  { :color => 'red', :animal => 'cat' },
  { :color => 'red', :animal => 'mouse' }
]
```

What I want to do is remove all but one of the duplicates based on one of the keys.

So in this case, I want to remove all but one of the items where `color` is `red`. Doesn't matter which one.

Final output would be something like this:

```
[
  { :color => 'blue', :animal => 'cat' },
  { :color => 'yellow', :animal => 'frog' },
  { :color => 'red', :animal => 'mouse' }
]
```

Again, when removing the duplicates, the one to keep does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

`.group_by { |x| x[:color] }.values.map(&:first)`

`.inject({}) { |xs, x| xs[x[:color]] = x; xs }.values`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of achieving this would be

```
.uniq { |h| h[:color] }
```

> => [{:color=>"red", :animal=>"dog"}, {:color=>"blue",
>   :animal=>"cat"}, {:color=>"yellow", :animal=>"frog"}]

As @Victor suggested this is for ruby 1.9.2+

Comment: 1.9.2+ (for those poor guys who are stuck with 1.8.7)